# Can't open or move widgets after Wordpress update

Tags: wordpress, widget

I recently updated my WordPress site `http://www.yourwhiteknight.com/` to 4.1.5 and found that I can't move or open any widgets on the widgets page. If I try to add one, I don't get the menu to add it to a widget and I can't drag and drop on into a sidebar. I can't click the down arrow on any widgets or on any sidebars that are not open in order to edit their contents.

I believe the version I was working with before was 3.5.2. I even tried to go to the customizer but it just gets stuck constantly trying to reload the page, some sort of redirect loop.

Has anyone had this problem before and can point me in the direction of a solution?

I am at a complete loss, other than uploading the older version of wordpress. If I do that, I don't know if the database will still work due to any changes in the DB from the upgrade. I can't revert to the old database because the client has already made a lot of changes.

Comment: I tried upgrading again to 4.2.2 but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is look for Javascript errors in the WordPress admin area using Dev Tools. The inability to move widgets or use other javascript functions in admin is common and a characteristic of Javascript conflicts with plugins or low-quality themes and the Javascript libraries that WordPress loads be default.

Use the developer tools in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) or [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what scripts are loading on your site - *I can see from my end that there are a lot of them* - and look in the console to see if there are errors. See [Using Your Browser to Diagnose JavaScript Errors.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Your_Browser_to_Diagnose_JavaScript_Errors)

If there are errors, deactivate plugins one by one and look for a theme update. It can take some time to find the cause of Javascript errors, and in some cases, you may need to debug yourself.